# Using a trigger on table in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am creating a trigger on the table below,

```
  CREATE TABLE test( id int auto_increment primary key,
              name varchar(40),
              debit decimal(19,2) default "0.00",
              fee decimal(19,2) default "0.00",
              balance decimal(19,2) default "0.00")
              ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Below also is the trigger code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_test BEFORE INSERT ON test t FOR EACH ROW
(select debit from test d where d.id="1")  
SET new.balance=30 + d.debit;
```

This trigger is suppose to update the test table(balance column) upon insertion into the test table.The trigger is suppose to select the debit value from the test table and add 30 before updating the balance column in the test table.But this query above wouldn't work.It keeps giving me this error

```
ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
```

Please I need help on how to figure what the problem is.Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the actual trigger body? What you showed is only an extract. Also, I'm not sure of your logic. Do you realise that `select debit from test d` will return more than one row, right?

Comment: Please I have Edited my trigger code.I am doing this in mysql 5.5. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_test BEFORE INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW
set @d=(select debit from test where id="1"),  
new.balance= 30 + Coalesce(@d,0);
```

The above code will work,try it and tell me your responds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_test BEFORE INSERT ON test t FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.balance=30 + (select debit from test d where d.id="1")
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort